# Hardware serial write arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

I am try to do a write to serial using a NANO. This is my current code

```js
#include "HardwareSerial.h"

long previousMillis = 0;
long interval = 2000;    

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
 pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if(currentMillis - previousMillis > interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis; 


    HardwareSerial serial = Serial;
    serial.write("hello");
  }
}
```

However when I monitor the serial using a serial monitor I only get

he

for each serial write. Please help

Comment: One thing I do have to use HardwareSerial and not the normal serial class unfortunately

Comment: Why are you creating a new HardwareSerial object in each iteration? You can just do `Serial.write()`. Not sure, but this might be the problem as you only call `begin()` on the global Serial object and I have no idea if that state gets tranfered during a copy.

Comment: In my main project which yields the same results I pass the Serial object into a function func(HardwareSerial serial) so the recreation isnt the issue

Comment: If you're passing it by value, as it seems you are doing, the exact same thing happens (a local copy is constructed). The `Serial` object is available globally so there is no need in making copies or passing it to functions.

Comment: Could you send the construction code to create the HardwareSerial instance

Comment: That's the point: it is already constructed and ready to use. Just write `Serial.write(...)` and see if that works. Even if the problem persists, this is what you should be doing.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean when you say you can't use the "normal serial class"? The default serial object (the global `Serial`) is of the class `HardwareSerial` which you say you must use.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the class type in my method from hardwareserial to stream &serial this is now working the way it should. Thanks for the help